# awakeFromFetch not called

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Core Data is working pretty smoothly in my app.  I can store and retrieve most of the data needed.  However,

- One object (ObjectW) hits awakeFromInsert, but never executes awakeFromFetch - data is never unarchived.
- Another object (ObjectX) executes awakeFromFetch fine - and data is unarchived.

Both ObjectW and ObjectX are stored in ObjectY.  Neither one has an explicit call to awakeFromFetch, just a reference to some properties.

```
- (void) awakeFromInsert {
    [super awakeFromInsert];
}


- (void) awakeFromFetch {
    NSLog(@"AWAKE FROM FETCH");
    [super awakeFromFetch];
}
```

Something went wrong.  Where do I look?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good discussion here

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/154453-awakefromfetch-when-it-is-called.html

In summary:  check to see if the method is capitalized and spelled correctly.  If so, the awakeFromFetch is not actually executed until an attribute  that is defined in the model is accessed.  Note it can be an actual attribute or defined as transient.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I am not calling the method directly, but I checked spelling on my references to the object properties. (edited to clarify)

Comment: You shouldn't have to call the method directly.  The docs state that it isn't necessarily called at fetch.  It is only called when you actually access an attribute.  AND only if that attribute is defined in the model.  You might want to double check that your attributes are defined in your model and not simply defined in your class files

Comment: "the awakeFromFetch is not actually executed until an attribute that is defined in the model is accessed" ... spot on! :)